# Understanding of uniform topology

Tags: general-topology

I am studying the uniform topology right now and I understand its basis element as a "strange" ball for which when your ball is too big, it includes everything in the space. But why this strange topology is important? I mean I don't see any advantage over the product topology. (where u just restrict to finitely many open sets)

Comment: The term *uniform topology* is ambiguous, see [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_topology). Which of the three possible definitions are you referring to?

Answer (score 5):

From your remarks I understand you mean the topology induced by the uniform metric on $\Bbb R^\omega$, i.e.: $$d(x,y) = \sup_{n \in \omega} \min(d(x_n, y_n),1)$$

This is a topology that is finer than the product topology but coarser than the box topology on that set. It’s not an important space in its own right, just a didactic example by Munkres. Quite a few exercises on it in his book. It serves to build intuition. It’s not applied elsewhere in maths AFAIK.